# Copy array field into another array faster

Tags: javascript, angular, algorithm

I have this snippet that copy a field from an array to another array field only if `account` from `usersList` is equal to `code` from `users_code`. This runs pretty slow. Is it there another way to make it run faster?

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.usersList.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < this.users_code.length; j++) {
        if (this.deductionsList[i].account == this.users_code[j].code) {
          this.deductionsList[i].name = this.users_code[j].name
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sorting index or directly sort the array `users_code` on the field code. Then you can enumerate the entries with a matching code by a dichotomic search followed by a linear search. This takes `O(log N + K)` operations rather than `O(N)`. (`N` is the length of `users_code` and `K` the number of matches.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.usersList.length; i++) {
    var userCode = this.users_code.find(function(user){
                         return user.code === this.deductionsList[i].account;
                   });
    this.deductionsList[i].name = userCode.name;
}
```

I believe that the find function is faster than itterating through the hole array. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1) you can get the length 1 time, not every `<` check (as in your code)

2) you can run through the `users_code` and make an object with code keys and name values:

```
const codeNames = this.users_code.reduce((result, e) => {
  result[e.code] = e.name;
  return result;
}, {});

this.usersList.forEach((e, i) => {
   this.deductionsList[i].name = codeNames[this.deductionsList[i].account] || this.deductionsList[i].name;
});
```

So, the compexity wil be ~ O(n + m), instead of O(n * m)